# .propertiestofetch to grab an array of properties in the CoreData entity in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to fetch a property in an entity. the property is `Double_t` type. My goal is to generate an `Array of [Double_t]` with all members of field "`readingNumber`", and pass it to `prepareForSegue` to make a graph in a different view. After run the following code, I was able to print the var `DistinctResults`, for example, as: `({readingNumber = 222;},{readingNumber = 114;},{readingNumber = 588;})` etc. Now I am facing the difficulty of generating the `Array of [222, 114, 588]`. Could someone give me a hint? Very much appreciate your help!! 
Best Regards.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

        let FetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "UserReading")
        FetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["readingNumber"]
        FetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType
        FetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true

            var DistinctResults: NSArray = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(FetchRequest, error: nil)!

            println(DistinctResults)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var clean: [String] = [""]

clean = [DistinctResults!.valueForKey("readingNumber")][0] as! [String]

...

return clean
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".